Issue in using astream_events in Flask for streaming data to the frontend
I'm unable to stream data to the frontend using astream_events. I'm working on a Langchain and Flask project.
My code related to the streaming:
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
        
        async def generate_response():
            response_chunks = []
            context_sources = set()

            try:
                # Streaming the events from LangChain's agent
                async for event in agent_executor.astream_events({"input": user_input, "chat_history": chat_history}, version="v1"):
                    print(event)
                    kind = event["event"]

                    # Handle different types of events
                    
                    
                    # Streaming content
                    if event["event"] == "on_chat_model_stream":
                        response_chunks.append(event["data"]["chunk"].content)
                        chain_response = event["data"]["chunk"].content.replace(' ', '<adding_space_token>')
                        yield f"data:{chain_response}\n\n"
                
                yield "data:[DONE]\n\n"

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error during streaming: {e}")
                yield f"data: ERROR: {str(e)}\n\n"
            finally:
                bot_response = ''.join(response_chunks)
                print(context_sources, ' :::context_sources')
                context_sources = set()
                # if len(bot_response) <= 0:
                #     return jsonify({'error': get_error_message(500)}), 500
                add_chat_message(session_id, user_input, bot_response, context_sources)
                handler = AsyncIteratorCallbackHandler()

        response = generate_response()
        print(response)
        return Response(stream_with_context(generate_response()), content_type='text/event-stream')
    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
        return jsonify({'error': get_error_message(500)}), 500```

When running astream_events code on colab everything works fine but when I try to do the same thing in my Flask API I face this issue:
<async_generator object send_message_route.<locals>.generate_response at 0x000001C970E4AAC0>
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\personal projects\Hi Edward\claims-coach-backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 256, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\personal projects\Hi Edward\claims-coach-backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\response.py", line 32, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable


I have solved the issue through using sockets.
My whole code:
@chatbot_controller.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
async def send_message_route():
    try:
        data = request.json
        session_id = data.get('session_id')
        user_input = data.get('user_input')
        user = g.user
        emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "Starting"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
        if not session_id or not user_input:
            return jsonify({'error': get_error_message(400)}), 400

        session =  get_session_chat(session_id)
        
        chat_history = []

        if session and 'messages' in session:
            for msg in session['messages']:
                user_message, bot_message = deserialize_message(msg)
                if user_message:
                    chat_history.append(user_message)
                if bot_message:
                    chat_history.append(bot_message)

        vector_store = get_vector_store()
        if vector_store is None:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Vector store initialization failed.'}), 500

        username = user['name']
        chat_model = get_large_language_model()
        prompt_template = create_prompt_template(f"When interacting with the user, refer to them as '{username}'. If the user requests to change their username, inform them that this can be done through the settings. If they ask for further instructions on how to do this, politely suggest they refer to the guide for more detailed steps. Try to keep your responses less then 100 words if possible. You will always output html")
        
        tools = [access_vector_store]
        
        agent = create_openai_tools_agent(chat_model, tools, prompt_template)

        agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
        response_chunks = []
        context_sources = []

        try:
            async for event in agent_executor.astream_events({"input": user_input, "chat_history": chat_history}, version="v1"):
                
                kind = event["event"]
                print(kind , ' ::::kind')
                # Handle different types of events
                if kind == "on_chain_start":
                    if (
                        event["name"] == "Agent"
                    ):  # Was assigned when creating the agent with `.with_config({"run_name": "Agent"})`
                        print(
                            f"Starting agent: {event['name']} with input: {event['data'].get('input')}"
                        )
                        emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "Thinking"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
                
                elif kind == "on_chain_end":
                    if (
                        event["name"] == "Agent"
                    ):  # Was assigned when creating the agent with `.with_config({"run_name": "Agent"})`
                        print(
                            f"Starting agent: {event['name']} with input: {event['data'].get('input')}"
                        )
                        emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "Thinking"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')

                
                if kind == "on_chat_model_stream":
                    chunk = event["data"]["chunk"].content
                    
                    response_chunks.append(chunk)
                    chain_response = chunk.replace(' ', '<adding_space_token>')
                    emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"data:{chain_response}\n\n", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "Streaming"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
                elif kind == "on_tool_start":
                    emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "tool"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
                elif kind == "on_tool_end":

                    emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "tool"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
                if kind == "on_retriever_end":
                    
                    
                    if 'output' in event['data']:
                        if 'documents' in event['data']['output']:

                            output = event['data']['output']
                            for doc in output['documents']:
                                document_title = doc.metadata.get('document_title', None)
                                doc_id = doc.metadata.get('document_reference_ID', None)
                                if doc_id:
                                    exists = any(item['doc_id'] == doc_id for item in context_sources)
                                    if not exists:
                                        context_sources.append({
                                            'doc_id': doc_id,
                                            'title': document_title
                                        })
                                           
                    emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': f"", 'session_id': session_id, "status": "tool", "context_sources": context_sources}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
            emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': '[DONE]', 'session_id': session_id}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error during streaming: {e}")
            emit(f'chat_response/{session_id}', {'chunk': str(e), 'session_id': session_id, "status": "Done"}, broadcast=True, namespace='/')
        finally:
            bot_response = ''.join(response_chunks)
            print(context_sources, ' :::context_sources')
            # if len(bot_response) <= 0:
            #     return jsonify({'error': get_error_message(500)}), 500
            add_chat_message(session_id, user_input, bot_response, context_sources)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
